# Exporting graphics as vector image

Tags: graphics3d, export, pdf-format, eps-format, svg-format

I am just trying to get my head around when mathematica stopped (largely 3D) exporting complex graphics as a vector image. I believe it was in one of the 11 versions.
I understand there are lots of issues with vector exports (like the well-known white lines around the edges, huge files, ...), but many of us had ways of dealing with that. It feels very retrograde to have to send high resolution bitmaps to journals for publication. Especially if you would like to combine plots, it just feels very clumsy.
Are there better work arounds? Did I miss something?

**A one line example:**

`Export["tst.svg",Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",    Mesh -> None]]`

Exports to an SVG file containing only a bitmap image (this is using 12.2 on linux, but I have tested the same on my Mac and, if I remember right, Windows:

`...<image id="image5" width="1500" height="1208"  ...`

Comment: Can you explain how you are "exporting" images?  There might be alternative ways giving the behaviour you are seeking.

Comment: E.g., `Export["tst.svg",Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Mesh -> None]]`

SVG: `<image id="image5" width="1500" height="1208"  ...`

Comment: @ Niels Walet Can you please post your code!

Comment: I just did in the comment; but I will do it in my text.

Comment: There is an issue with `ColorFunction` and rasterizing exported plots - see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246196/prevent-rasterization-of-a-simple-plot-with-a-colorfunction).

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92133/1871

Comment: @xzczd no. That is a different issue (mathematica 10 still did vector exports).

Comment: @MelaGo That may be related. I still do not understand when, how, and why this changed, because older versions of MMA definitely did not have this issue.

Comment: also in version 13 i dont manage to make any of the proposed solution to work